# Imported video is in slow-motion

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I imported a video file (an interview with a person, mp4) of 60 fps into the Video Sequence Editor. The idea is to superimpose a Blender animation that has 24 fps. Unfortunately but not surprisingly, the video (not its audio) plays in slow motion.

Too much work has gone into the animation to convert it to 60 fps. Can Blender convert the video file from 60 fps to 24 fps? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HandBreak to transcode your footage into the needed framerate, or you could render your animation alone and edit it together in a dedicated video editor like Premier, Kdenlive, etc. Blender can be used to transcode but its not the most convenient way.